# install python kivy on fedora 19

Tags: python, repository, fedora, kivy

I want to install python kivy on fedora 19 .All repo's have introduced in official site related to fedora 18-17-16 .
How I could install it on fedora 19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not personally installed it but came across this link.

http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/23804520/dir/fedora_19/com/python-kivy-1.6.0-5.1.x86_64.rpm.html